# jquery script not running

Tags: jquery, html

I have two pages. First one is index.html which has a script to load a second page. The second page has a jquery script that is supposed to run and show a alert.

In the code that is shown below i have removed all extra stuff to simplify my question.

Code for index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Testing</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./review/includes/look.css" />
  </head>
  <body class="review offline" tabindex="0">
    <div id="sidepanel" class="hidden">
      <div class="section" >
        <div id="navigation" class="rounded-border">
          <ul id="navigationtree">
            <li class="leaf last" title="Home">
              <ins class="icon">&nbsp;</ins><a href="screens/alertPage" tabindex="-1"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="jim-mainWindow">
        <div id="jim-body" class="full web" >
            <div id="simulation" class="firer"></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./review/includes/j.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){jimMain.init("screens/alertPage");});</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code for the second page is:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            alert("hi there");
            }
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

1) I have made sure the jquery-1.10.1.js page is in the same directory as alertPage.html
2) I have validated that alertPage.html is actually being loaded by index.html by adding from UI to alertPage and seeing it being rendered.

What am i missing here?

Comment: you forgot to include `jquery` in the first html file

Comment: you wrote .ready( ... }

Comment: @karthikr the index.html has j.js and it is properly loading the second alertPage.html as i noted.

Comment: if you are .loading the second page... don't include jquery again because it will overwrite the jquery on the original page. It's generally a bad idea to .load in html that contains javascript anyway.

Comment: @kevin if i was to move the script from alertPage to index.html can i refer to the div in alertPage.html from the script in index.html?

Comment: Yes, if it's ran AFTER you append the content of alertPage.html to index.html

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: juhana i dont see any errors being captured by firebug.

Answer (score 4):

Missing `)`, extra `}`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert("hi there");
    //Remove the }
}); //<---Add the );
```

Comment: this did not do the trick. Still do not see the alert popup. I am testing on the latest version of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Load your custom js after you have loaded in jQuery

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./review/includes/j.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        alert("hi there");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: that did not make a change. the custom js is on index.html and the jquery-1.10.1.js is being loaded on alertPage.html.

Comment: Does the custom js file contain jQuery? If so, you will need to include that in your index.html.

Comment: i included the line as you suggest but that did not change the output.

Comment: @codeNinja - grrr!!! OK update your question to include your custom js and I will try and reproduce the error using all your code.